# Android Studio and environment variables

Tags: android-studio, environment-variables, java-home

In my "user variables" I have ANDROID_HOME, GRADLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

Android studio is giving me the following warning:

"*Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different. Project 'MyApp' is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr' The system environment variable JAVA_HOME is: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15' If you dont need to use different paths (or if JAVA_HOME is undefined), you can avoid spawning multiple daemons by setting JAVA_HOME and the JDK location to the same path.*"

What is the difference with ANDROID_HOME, GRADLE_HOME and JAVA_HOME?
Do I just delete Gradle home?
Can I delete any of them down to just JAVA_HOME?

any help would be grateful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would click on **File -> Settings** then search for Gradle, then check the **Gradle JDK path** and compare it with my JAVA_HOME where I installed my jdk.

Comment: the gradle is version 17 and JAVA_HOME is 15, do I just delete JAVA_HOME?

Comment: It works for me like that: If I have a project which requires for example JDK 17, I set JAVA_HOME and Gradle JDK Path to the same JDK. Then it works. They should be the same. Which JDK does your project need?

Answer (score 0):

Now with [JBR](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#:%7E:text=To%20modify%20the%20existing%20project%27s,such%20as%20JAVA_HOME%20and%20GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME) in windows use `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin` at SYSTEM ENV add path variable,